# Why p-norm($p\neq 1,2,\infty$) of a real matrix is not the same when it's seen as a complex matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

$A$ is real $n\times n$ matrix .I have known $sup\{\frac{||Ax||_{p}}{||x||_{p}};x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},x\neq0\}=sup\{\frac{||Ax||_{p}}{||x||_{p}};x\in\mathbb{C}^{n},x\neq0\}$ holds when $p=1,2,\infty$.I also wonder why the equality does not hold in other cases.Any help will be thanked.

Answer (score 1):

The equality between real and complex norm actually holds true for any $ 1 \leqslant p \leqslant \infty $. More generally, one may wonder what happens for the operator norm $ \| A\|_{p,q,\mathbb{F}} = \sup \{ \| Ax \|_q / \|x\|_p, x \in \mathbb{F}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} \}$ with $ \mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R} $ or $ \mathbb{C} $ and $ 1 \leqslant p,q \leqslant \infty $ and determine when do we have $ \| A\|_{p,q,\mathbb{C}} = \| A\|_{p,q,\mathbb{R}} $ for a $ m \times n $ real matrix $ A $. Several authors have contributed:

- when $ 1 \leqslant p \leqslant q \leqslant \infty $, this is claimed in the paper of M. Riesz on (real) interpolation https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-49/issue-3-4/Sur-les-maxima-des-formes-bilin%c3%a9aires-et-sur-les-fonctionnelles/10.1007/BF02564121.full (page 491), but the proof, based on differential calculus, is sketchy;
- A. E. Taylor in 1958 https://www.unige.ch/math/EnsMath/EM_fr/welcome.html gives a complete proof of the case $ 1 \leqslant p \leqslant q \leqslant \infty $ by using differential calculus.
- the case $ 1 \leqslant p = q \leqslant \infty $ was also proved A. Zygmund in 1959 in his book Trigonometric Series (Chapter IV, Exercise 13) by expressing the modulus of a complex as an $L^p$ norm. This trick was generalized to the case $ 1 \leqslant p \leqslant q \leqslant \infty $ by I.E. Verbickii and P.P. Sereda in 1975.
- the case $ 1 \leqslant p = q \leqslant \infty $ was also proved by M. Crouzeix in 1986 https://www.esaim-m2an.org/articles/m2an/abs/1986/03/m2an1986200304271/m2an1986200304271.html via differential calculus.

More general result (with $L^p$ and $L^q$ spaces) have been given in

- J. Gasch and L. Maligranda https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/mana.19941670106 and https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1012356/FULLTEXT01.pdf
- O. Holtz and M. Karow https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512608.pdf (unpublished).

If $ 1 \leqslant q < p \leqslant \infty $, it may happen that $ \| A\|_{p,q,\mathbb{R}} < \| A\|_{p,q,\mathbb{C}} $. For instance, with $ B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $, one may check that $ \|B\|_{\infty,1,\mathbb{R}} = 2 < 2 \sqrt{2} = \| B \|_{\infty,1,\mathbb{C}} $.